# How to get rid from Cross domain origin error in OpenCart

Tags: php, cross-domain, opencart

I have made a site with open cart plugin, the problem I face is when I am going to access my website in my PC using `localhost/mywebsite`, it works like a charm but when I try to open my website in another PC in LAN using my IP address `192.168.1.20/mywebsite` it doesn't get loaded properly i.e. images, icon doesn't get loaded. When I tried to replicate error in developer console of browser it was showing an error of `Cross Domain Origin`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have got a hard coded host name somewhere. You can replace hard coded host references with defined constants:

```
$SCHEME = (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) AND $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
define('SCHEME', $SCHEME);
define('DOMAIN', $SCHEME . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
```

For example, `localhost/page.html` becomes `SCHEME.DOMAIN."/page.html"`

There is documentation on [server variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and the [define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) method.